# Flex Advance datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

By any chance is there a way I can show "Barbara Jennings" row next to "Arizona" folder. I know its not possible because those two records are grouped by "Arizona" and displayed under group field "Arizona" , but for one of my requirment I want to show whole grouped records start from the parent level even if the "Arizona" is closed one record should be visible. Please refer to the expected o/p screen below.

I tried Flex libs windows shade the only problem I see with window shade is I have to manually(Through Action script) take care of UI validation / In validation.

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: Am using the Flex doc sample code only , http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_02.html. the screens I shared is created in photoshop.

Comment: The functionality you want is not available in the AdvancedDataGrid, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It is possible. But it is going to be very ugly )

In AdvancedDataGrid you are able to detect when you open or close the row.

When you do that, you can simply go through the objects in your dataprovider array and change properties that are datafields.

The algorithm will look like:
If the item is opened, copy properties from first child to parent, from second child to first child, etc, and erase properties from the last child. You can add some flags to the objects, that will determine whether the object was opened or was closed..

Something like that :)

Comment: I agree , do you have nay idea other than Advance datagrid? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Well, you also can wright somethink like you own datagrid. Some repeaters, panels that will collapse and so on. But it is time-eating experiment.

Comment: "time-eating" exactly , I got this output using few list inside VBox . .

Answer (score 0):

Set default leaf icon to null to hide it

```
 <mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%" defaultLeafIcon="{null}">
```